# UI-Router - scope not destroyed on state change?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui, state

I'm a new user to AngularJS and ui-router, and I'm trying to turn my head around on how the scope is managed. I was expecting the scope of an active controller would be destroyed when it becomes inactive on state change, however, it doesn't appear to be the case.

I've modified the example from UI-Router's website to illustrate the situation (see plunker below). Every time when the state route1.list/route2.list is triggered, they will emit an event on $rootScope. On receiving the event, a debug statement will be printed to console.

By toggling between the two states a few times, it is observed that all the controllers initialized previously responded the the event. So it appears that the scopes created by them have never been destroyed. Is this behavior expected? If so, what should I do such that only active controllers will respond to an event?

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TshSHQLE2Iwn0br15y4h?p=preview)

Debug message printed on Console:
[image]

Code:

```
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ["ui.router"])
myapp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider){

// For any unmatched url, send to /route1
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/route1")
```

here is the route1

```
$stateProvider
  .state('route1', {
      url: "/route1",
      templateUrl: "route1.html"
  })
    .state('route1.list', {
        url: "/list",
        templateUrl: "route1.list.html",
        controller: function($rootScope, $scope){
          $rootScope.$emit("eventCT1");
          $rootScope.$on("eventCT2", fn);
          function fn () {
            console.log("Controller 1 receives an event emitted by Controller 2");
          }
          $scope.items = ["A", "List", "Of", "Items"];
        }
    })
```

and here is route 2

```
  .state('route2', {
      url: "/route2",
      templateUrl: "route2.html"
  })
    .state('route2.list', {
        url: "/list",
        templateUrl: "route2.list.html",
        controller: function($rootScope, $scope){
          $rootScope.$emit("eventCT2");
          $rootScope.$on("eventCT1", fn);
          function fn () {
            console.log("Controller 2 receives an event emitted by Controller 1");
          }
          $scope.things = ["A", "Set", "Of", "Things"];
        }
    })
 ...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we want to do something with

1)  **`$rootScope`** inside of the controller *(which has very limited lifetime)*,

2) we must destroy that, when controller *(its `$scope` in fact)* is being destroyed

So, this is the way how to hook and unhook

```
// get remove function
var removeMe = $rootScope.$on("eventCT2", ...);

// call that function
$scope.$on("$destroy", removeMe)
```

But, in the case above, we should not even try to

1) create some controller action for one state...

2) and expect it will be called in another controller from different state

These will never live together

Comment: Thanks for your help. There's one thing I don't quite understand though - if the previous controller is destroyed on state change, shouldn't the listener registered with $rootScope.$on(name, listener) become undefined? Why would it still be triggered and there's no error thrown?

Comment: That is "closure". The whole object, representing controller (and all that does reference) is kept in memory... to be able to serve as listener. That is the *best way* how to create memory leaks. I suggest, read about closures, and mostly do **NOT** use the `$rootScope` without unregistering on controller level. Hope it helps a bit. Enjoy UI-Router and angular and you can evne accept the answer if that helped you...

Comment: I don't see why this is the accepted answer. I have the same problem and you can't use that destroy call because destroy is never getting called on state change.

Comment: @StevenWade state change and scope destroy are not related... therefore it is not surprising that destroy is never getting called on state change. It is called when state view gets out of the *scope*, but what is your problem? Do you have more details? any Question here?

Comment: @StevenWade but do you know what... I guess that your issue is related to VIEW caching! Check this to get more details http://stackoverflow.com/q/31073765/1679310. Also, there is an example of how the destroy is REALLY called http://stackoverflow.com/a/28579793/1679310

Comment: @RadimKöhler http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35076821/broadcast-to-current-scope

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Ionic with Angular, you could use the [life cycle events](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/) like so:

```
$scope.$on("$ionicView.beforeEnter", function(){
   //Do something every time this controller is the active scope.
})
```

You could play around with the other events provided in the above link as well. And it's probably best practise to minimize the use of `$emit`, which will lead to more predictable code and fewer state mutations.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Unfortunately my project is not using Ionic framework, and I don't foresee it'll be. So I probably have to explore other options.