# $broadcast to current scope

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

To preface, I have an Ionic app connected to a Node server via a websocket and the Node server is connected to a C++ app via a TCP socket. I have this service that connects and serves up the socket but also watches for a `nack` response so that it can issue an alert notifying the user of the error:

```
(function(){
  'use strict';

  angular.module('tacoCorp.services')
    .factory('Socket', Socket);

  Socket.$inject = ['socketFactory', 'OSDP', '$rootScope'];

  function Socket(socketFactory, OSDP, $rootScope) {
    var socket = io('localhost:3000');

    socket = socketFactory({ioSocket: socket});

    socket.on('connect', function() {
        console.log('connected');
    });

    socket.on('nack', function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        var error = OSDP.parse(data);
        $rootScope.$broadcast('nack', error);
    });

    return socket;
  }
}());
```

I have this in each controller listening so that it can issue the popup:

```
$scope.$on('nack', function(e, err) {
        console.log(err);
        var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
            title: 'Error',
            template: err.error
        });
    });
```

My problem is that it is firing multiple times even though my there is only one controller for each state/view. Almost as if `$destroy` isn't happening or it's not removing the listener. Still happens if I do this:

```
var nackListener = $scope.$on('nack', function(e, err) {
        console.log(e);
        var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
            title: 'Error',
            template: err.error
        });
    });

    $scope.$on('$destroy', nackListener);
```

I'm not sure what the best way to handle this is.

Comment: Create another function that gets called on $destroy, the function will console out a test message and also call your cancel function.  That'll tell you of your controller is getting destroyed at least.

Comment: Change the caching strategy as discussed here http://stackoverflow.com/a/31074503/1679310. Or hook on the events fired by IONIC which are there to be a workaround for caching http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionView/

Comment: @RadimKöhler I can see that there is `$ionicView.leave`, but how do you remove the listener without destroy?

Comment: Do all you have to do is pass the function to `$scope.$on('$ionicView.leave')` and angular magically removes the listener?

Comment: I would say, that you just have to remove that from cached views. I.e. something like: `$scope.$on("$ionicView.leave",nackListener)`.... that is not MAGICALLY. There is no magic at all. That is about the fact that 1) when the event $ionicView.leave is fired - 2) the REMOVE method nackListener is called 3) because the nackListener is a reference to REMOVE WATCH method... no magic

Comment: @RadimKöhler But if you do that, the event isn't instantiated when you come back to the controller.

Comment: Well, look.. that is obvious right? ;) because **you've removed that watch**. In fact.. your problem is that what you are building - is not ready to coexist with caching. Wow... that is it. Check my link and turn off cache for socket communication. By the essence of your target (using sockets) your app can hardly profit from view caching... would that make sense?

Comment: I will try it with the `$ionicConfigProvider.views.maxCache(0)`, but doing `cache:false` isn't changing anything.

Comment: @RadimKöhler `$ionicConfigProvider.views.maxCache(0)` did the trick where `cache:false` did not. Also found that you can do this `$ionicHistory.clearCache()`, but that clears too much for me. EDIT: they both do the same thing.

Comment: Glad to help.. glad you finally got it

Comment: @RadimKöhler It works for me for now, but if you know a way to only remove/add the listener that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

As [Radim Köhler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1679310/radim-k%C3%B6hler) pointed out `$ionicConfigProvider.views.maxCache(0)` fixes this issue where `cache:false` on the state does not. You could also do this:

```
$scope.$on("$ionicView.afterLeave", function () {
        $ionicHistory.clearCache();
    });
```

Best way for me is to just pick one controller to put it on and be done with it.